# Adding leftbarbuttonitem to UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have to customise `UIImagePickerController` (adding left bar button item and removing right bar button item) as follows:

[image: UIImagePickerController]

I tried to achieve this:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]]) {
        [viewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Gallery"];
        UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;             
        UINavigationItem *top = bar.topItem;
        UIBarButtonItem *leftBarNuttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CancelIcon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissImagePickerView)];
        top.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        top.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarNuttonItem;
    }
}
```

But it is not happening. Help me to resolve it.

Comment: By "not happening", do you mean the left bar button item does not show up at all?

Comment: @cpatmulloy : yes.. Left bar button item is showing and immediately disappears. Then right bar item button is visible.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

> Important
>
> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
>   class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
>   The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified,
>   with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
>   cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
>   information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
>   and your code.